# Defining a method definition for an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an interface that I'm designing.  Let's call it, "IMyInterface".  Each class that implements IMyInterface is going to have N steps.  One of the methods in my in IMyInterface is going to be `GetData(int StepNumber)`.  GetData needs to return an ObservableCollection which will be a collection of some class that changes depending on the step we're on.  For example, if class ModelA implements iMyInterface and ModelA has 2 steps, then calling `ModelAInstance.GetData(1)` might return an `ObservableCollection<ClassX>`.  Calling `ModelAInstance.GetData(2)` might return `ObservableCollection<ClassY>`.  Etc.

For some reason, I'm having trouble coming up with the method declaration for GetData.  I could use:

```
ObservableCollection<object> GetData(int StepID);
```

but that doesn't seem right to me.  I think there's a better way to do this with generics, right?

Comment: Looks like you'll need a union type... what kind of commonality exists between the types you'll need?

Comment: How would the caller know that `GetData(2)` should return `ClassY` or `ClassX`?

Comment: Do both ClassX and ClassY have something in common? Maybe a shared interface?

Comment: @Matthew - I think we can make this clear in the return type. It won't be as clean as say F# but it should work well.

Comment: Is the number of steps fixed? If so you could have N type parameters in `IMyInterface` for the return types of each step and you can have methods `GetStepOne`, `GetStepTwo` etc.

Comment: @ChaosPandion My concern was if these two types are significantly different, it may not be possible to have a common interface between them.  Unfortunately from the question it doesn't say what the differences or commonalities between `ClassX` and `ClassY` are.

Comment: There isn't necessarily any commonality between ClassX and ClassY (or any of the other possibilities.)  The results of GetData are going to be passed to a DataGrid for display.  (But the interface shouldn't know or care about that.)

Comment: @Lee - Could get out of hand but it should work well as long as the number of steps is small.

Comment: @Lee: No the number of steps is not fixed.

Comment: If the types `ClassX` and `ClassY` have nothing in common, `ObservableCollection<object>` might be the best choice; however this might indicate a design weakness.

Comment: @Matthew:  Good question.... I'm not coming up with a good answer for that one.  Maybe `ObservableCollection<object>` is the right way to go, after all?

Comment: @Codor:  Argh.  I think you might be right.  I'm starting to think that I'm attacking this problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<object>` simply sounds like your design model is a bit weak.

Comment: I would try and approach this from the callers perspective, as a lot of the times the use-cases (callers) determine how the interface looks.

Comment: Do your callers know what type of data `GetData` should return? Because you could just do `ObservableCollection<T> GetData<T>(int stepId);`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: That's actually where I started.  Then I realized that the callers didn't know.  The callers (at least in this case) just want an ObservableCollection that can be used to populate a DataGrid.  But perhaps I need to go back to the initial designer and discuss this in further detail with him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the existing comments, if the return type is enough to specify to the user what to expect back from a call, then you should just be able to include that type in the call itself.

```
ObservableCollection<T> GetData<T>(int StepID);
```

In which case it could simply be called as such:

```
ModelAInstance.GetData<ClassX>(1);
ModelAInstance.GetData<ClassY>(2);
```

On that note, I would wonder if the step number is necessary any longer (unless of course it is used for other logic within the method).

Edit: Clumsy me.  I didn't notice the linked extra comments.  Should this solution work, I defer to Mike who provided the same answer in comments before me.

Comment: Well, after discussing the application needs with the designer, the actual solution was to return an `ObservableCollection<object>`.  I'm not thrilled about that, but that's what we're going with.  In a more perfect world, I believe that this would have been a better design.  Thanks to OhBeWise and Mike McCaughan (and everyone) for your help.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer.